# Problems with Drawer Navigation in Android

Tags: android

I was using the Drawer Navigation which provide by android developer website. The things were I have one of my menubar at the bottom then when I slide the sliding menu out then it was cover my bottom menubar, and that was the problem. Plz help

Comment: Can you show your related code and xml file too??

Comment: Nice story bro, what's the question? Where is your code, your errors?

Comment: why cant you add this menu bar to action bar??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate your menu like this :

```
 public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
        {
            float moveFactor = (yourDrawer.getWidth() * slideOffset);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) 
            {
                if(drawerView.getRight()==moveFactor) {
                    yourMenu.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
                }
            }
        }
```